# useQuery (from React Query) with React Hook Form throws Invalid Hook Call

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-query

Getting below error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

My Sign In Form

```js
export const SignInView: FC<{ path: string }> = (): ReactElement => {
  type Inputs = {
    userId: string;
  };

 function fetchUser(id: string): UseQueryResult {
  return useQuery('fetchUser', async () => {
    const response: Response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/users/" + id, RequestInit = {method: 'GET'});
    return response;
  });
}

  const { register, handleSubmit, getValues, errors, setError } = useForm<Inputs>();

  const onSubmit = (): void => {
    const { userId } = getValues();
    //throws Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
    const { data } = fetchUser(userId);
   //....some logic here.
}

return (
    <div className='container container-rounded border w-25 bg-white text-center'>
      <div className='row p-2 mt-2 text-center'>
        <div className='col'>
          <p className='h3' data-content='header'>
            Demo
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='row p-2'>
        <div className='col'>
          <h5>Sign in</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col form-group'>
            <Form.Control
              type='text'
              name='userId'
              autoFocus
              ref={register({ required: true })}
              className='form-control form-control-lg'
              placeholder='User ID'
              data-field='userId'
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='row p-2'>
          <div className='col text-center'>
            <Button
              type='submit'
              className='default btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button-rounded'
              data-action='sign-in'>
              Sign in
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Form>
)
```

I have seen suggestions that say `useMutation` instead and invoke `mutate` callback function but this is a GET call, so `useQuery` is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is correct as you are trying to call the hook not inside the body of the `<SignInView />` component.

As you are returning a `useQuery` hook from your `fetchUser` function it's also a react convention to use the "use" prefix for your custom hook, so you can call it just `useUser`.

You can get your use case to work by invoking the call to your api manually. Just set the query's `enabled` config option to `false` and trigger the fetch by using `refetch` in your `onSubmit` callback.

Then use RHF's `watch` to pass the current value of your `<Form.Control />` to your `useUser` hook.

```js
function useUser(id: string): UseQueryResult {
  return useQuery('fetchUser', async () => {
    const response: Response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/users/" + id, RequestInit = {method: 'GET'});
    return response;
  }, { enabled: false });
}
```

```js
export const SignInView: FC<{ path: string }> = (): ReactElement => {
 const { register, handleSubmit, errors, setError, watch } = useForm<Inputs>();
 const userId = watch('userId');
 const { refetch } = useUser(userId);

 const onSubmit = async (): void => {
  const { data } = await refetch();
  //....some logic here.
 }

return (...);
}
```